# Using Upstart after building Apache & Mysql from source

Tags: mysql, upstart, apache2

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, Apache 2.2.17 and Mysql 5.5.10.

I need some assistance getting Apache and Mysql running on boot.

Reading the getting started over at upstart website attempting to get it to work.

I added `/etc/init/apache2.conf`

along with the following line:

`exec /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl`

I'm probably doing everything wrong, could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upstart's method of following forks isn't really suited to apache unfortunately (there's a new method in development, `expect exit` which will handle this). So for now the init.d script is probably fine.

If you really need to have apache start before/after some other upstart job.. you can do

```
start on started otherjob
stop on stopping otherjob

pre-start exec /usr/local/bin/apachectl start

post-stop exec /usr/local/bin/apachectl stop
```

For mysql, I'd recommend installing the mysql package and using its upstart job, just change the paths to use your installed binaries.

Comment: Where can I find mysql's upstart job?

Comment: /etc/init/mysql.conf the source is in the packaging branch at https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5

Comment: @SpamapS isnt that the Precise development version?

Comment: Yes, I would assume if you are going to run MySQL "not from the repo" that you want 5.5... it should work fine going back to lucid.

Answer (score 0):

for running apache in boot:

```
update-rc.d -f apache remove
```

and

```
update-rc.d apache2 start 88 2 3 . stop 0 1 6 .
```

And for mysqld too.

Comment: This is great and all. But I really wanted to learn how to use Upstart.